# Move section to next page if the section won't fit to the existing page. Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I need to use Crystal report for document design.

I have multiple subreports/sections in main report. These subreports/sections are meant to display comments with dynamic rows coming from database.

- I want to move the section to the next page, if the information/comments under the section won't fit to the same page, else display it under the same page.

How can I achieve this? Can someone help me with the formula or any settings under Section Expert?

Answer (score 0):

In Section Expert, turn on the ***Keep Togethe***r option for that section.